# Authlete OAuth endpoint to retrieve claims data

Tags: authentication, oauth, authlete

I'm trying to setup an authorization flow with Authlete, but I can't seem to figure out how I retrieve the claim data.

/auth/authorization <- gains me a ticket

/auth/authorization/issue <- allows me to set the claim data and retrieve token

However,

/auth/introspection <- does not return the claim data (just the list of claims)

/auth/userinfo <- does not return the claim data.

What is the endpoint to pass in the auth token and get the claim data?

Answer (score 1):

`/auth/introspection` is an API to get information about an access token. Its response does not include any information about claims.

`/auth/userinfo` is an API to parse a request to your [UserInfo Endpoint](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo) from a client application. Its response includes a list of claims whose values you are supposed to retrieve from your database.

The next step you should do is to pass the values of the claims to `/auth/userinfo/issue` API. The API's response contains a plain JSON or an [ID token](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) (which is a kind of [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519)). **Claim values are included there.**

Please check the following open source repositories to see how [Authlete APIs](https://www.authlete.com/documents/apis) are called.

1. [java-oauth-server](https://github.com/authlete/java-oauth-server) (Authorization Server / OpenID Provider)
2. [java-resource-server](https://github.com/authlete/java-resource-server) (Resource Server)
3. [authlete-java-common](https://github.com/authlete/authlete-java-common) (Wrapper library over Authlete APIs)
4. [authlete-java-jaxrs](https://github.com/authlete/authlete-java-jaxrs) (Utility library for JAX-RS)

You can find an example of UserInfo Endpoint implementation in `UserInfoEndpoint.java` (in [java-resource-server](https://github.com/authlete/java-resource-server)). The `UserInfoEndpoint` class extends `BaseUserInfoEndpoint` class (in [authlete-java-jaxrs](https://github.com/authlete/authlete-java-jaxrs)).

Any additional questions are welcome. I'm a co-founder of [Authlete](https://www.authlete.com/) and the one who has designed and implemented all the [Authlete APIs](https://www.authlete.com/documents/apis) :-)

Comment: Thank you, a question I have is if I can set the claim data in the /auth/authorization/issue call, who is the consumer of this?  Or does the auth token flow ignore this data, presumably it would be made available through a JWT flow?

Comment: @user1432403 I'm not sure I understand your additional question correctly, but the direct consumer of a response from /auth/authorization/issue API is your UserInfo endpoint implementation. Your UserInfo Endpoint implementation extracts the value of `responseContent` from the API response and returns the value to the client application which has made the original request to your UserInfo Endpoint. In that sense, the client application is the final (indirect) consumer. BTW, what do you mean by "auth token flow" and "JWT flow"?

Answer (score 0):

I guess values of claim should be passed in string. (e.g. `"claims": "{\"email\":\"mail@example.com\",\"email_verified\":true}"`) if not, you cannot `retrieve` the claim `data`.